# Написание функции в sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin4

Хочу написать простую функцию,которая возвращает все строки в таблице. Какое возвращаемое значение должно быть у функции?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно указать `setof имя_таблицы`. Формально `setof` требует указания типа данных, но любого типа - в том числе композитного. А каждая таблица неявно создаёт одноименный композитный тип описывающий собственную структуру.

```
create function return_table_am() 
returns setof am 
as $$ 
    select * from am;
$$ language sql;
```